# Error The action "Run Shell Script" (Image to Card)" encountered an error

Tags: raspbian, pi-2

As the title says, when I try to format my micro SD card using [RPi-sd card builder](https://alltheware.wordpress.com/2012/12/11/easiest-way-sd-card-setup/) I keep getting an error saying:

```
The action "Run Shell Script (Image to Card)" encountered an error.
```

I'm not quite sure what is going wrong here, help is appreciated.

I'm using OS X El Capitan and RPi-sd card builder v1.2

Comment: A screen shot of this would be nice.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, and finally determined it was because there was a space in the containing folder name.

I had it on my desktop in a folder marked "Card Builder" and when I changed it to "CardBuilder" it worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

I have never heard of "RPi-sd card builder v1.2". Where did you get it and why?

Why not just follow the recommended installation procedure:- 
https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/installation/installing-images/mac.md

Comment: Never had I. However, I've added a link to it, in the OP's question. It is linked to on the [RPi Easy SD Card Setup](http://elinux.org/RPi_Easy_SD_Card_Setup#Flashing_the_SD_card_using_Mac_OS_X) page.